# UI Updates getting lost after new Deployment with Overwrite of the App

Tags: maui

I have a problem when deploying my App in Release mode on my iPhone.

When I delete my App on my iPhone and Deploy the App it works - "it works" means, I can do Updates of items in my Database via UI and in other Views they get updated with the changes and I can see these changes in the UI as expected.

In case I do not delete my App before deploying it again, I can do the Updates of items in my Database via UI as before, but the other Views do not get updated with the changes.

In this case it appears as if I had forgotten to use OnPropertyChanged(...) in my code and therefore the updates are missing. But, I checked and they are definitively available and also it would not have worked after the initial deploy if this was a problem in my Code.

Is this a Bug or normal for such a case or do I have to do something to register it again after App "Updates"?

Comment: Is there a way I can reproduce this?

Comment: Hhm, what I have is a .NET MAUI App with .NET 7, Entity Framework for the Database and then normal Databinding activities in different Views sharing Properties in a ViewModel. Then the Workflow is as described in this Question. Deploy the App in Release Mode on real Hardwarde (iOS). Do an Update of a value in the Database and get this Value in the corresponding Property in the ViewModel. See the updated Value in the UI. Then delete obj/bin and (+ Clean) and deploy again on real Hardware. Do the same steps to Update and see that they are not visible in the UI View. Don't know why :(

Comment: Are there routines which allow me to re-initialize the DataBinding mechanisms with notifications again for sure in my App? If so, I would do that. I can't prove it, but to me it appears like they get lost, when I re-install my App. Currently, for me it was too early to switch to .NET 8 due to the Bug-Situation, but I am interested to see if it is the same there. Maybe I can switch over to give it a try in the next couple of days